# how can make this code in to a callable method class

Tags: java, android, class, methods

I have these 2 lines of code that get called over and over. At the moment every time I want to use it I type it in. Was wondering how to put it into a callable method/class that I could instead something like `FileLocation();` Thanks as always and I hope I have asked in the right way?

```
//App Location Tools
File StorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
String StorageDownloads = StorageDirectory.getAbsolutePath() + "/Download";
```

Then to call it I say

```
File Allcastfile = new File(StorageDownloads, "Each file i use");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don´t understand exactly what You want, and I guess that´s the reason why nobody give You an answer until now. But if I try to guess what exactly You mean, I think You only don´t want to type this line of code every time You need it, right? So, for this small two lines, there is only a little bit of optimization. You can do it like this to get everytime the same folder path:

```
private String getFolderPath(){

File StorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
String StorageDownloads = StorageDirectory.getAbsolutePath() + "/Download";
return StorageDownloads;

}
```

and then You can always call:

```
String path = getFolderPath();
```

If this is not Your intension, You should make Your question a little bit more clear.

the other way is to make a global String:

```
private String StorageDownloads="";
```

and after `setContentView` in Your activity (for example):

```
File StorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
StorageDownloads = StorageDirectory.getAbsolutePath() + "/Download";
```

then You can use storageDownloads every time You need.

Comment: I have to admit....20 years ago....maybe it changed since that time....like the german spelling reform...

Comment: thanks @Opiatefuchs and sorry for any confusion. i would like it in a class on its own pehaps and just call it with the getFolerPath(); You mentioned

Comment: can we not argue please guys i aint bothered about capital letters lol

Comment: not? ....mmmm...anyway, learned a new thing. maybe my brain is too squishy from abusing substances all the years....

Comment: Found it. Anyways, I would suggest you had a parameter to `getFolderPath` that would replace `/Download`... http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30185/you-versus-you-as-polite-form-of-writing

Comment: You are a funny guy cricket_007, nice to argue about spelling forms in a coding forum:) ....so now the capital you was right because of starting a sentence... ;)

Comment: You´re welcome Mark  ....(or is it "you´re welcome Mark"?.....bzzz....brain tilt)...